# Why Application.get_Caller(Type.Missing) returns a negative integer?

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop, vsto

There's something weird about `get_Caller(Type.Missing)` method. It returns a negative integer, **-2146826265**, instead of the **Range** object as it should.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Why is that and how should I solve it?

Thanks.

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range) application.get_Caller(System.Type.Missing);
```

The above code would fail if I try to explicitly user type `Excel.Range`. The error message says, 'Cannot convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'.

EDIT:

The intention of getting caller of the cell is to pass it to my following function:

```
private string getResultFromResultSheet(Excel.Range originalSheetRange, Excel.Worksheet resultSheet)
        {
            string DataResult = "";
            try
            {
                string os_currentAddress = originalSheetRange.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Excel.Range currentRRange = null;

                currentRRange = resultSheet.get_Range(os_currentAddress, Type.Missing);
                if (currentRRange != null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(currentRRange.Value)))
                        DataResult = "";
                    else
                        DataResult = Convert.ToString(currentRRange.Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return DataResult;
        }
```

With the return value from that function, I can pass it back to UDF and display it in the original cell. Is there any better way to implement the function?

Comment: looks like a HResult to me. Unfortunately searching for 800a07e7 didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: can you specify the page please? I couldn't find it through google search.

Answer (score 2):

Review the table at the end of this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.caller.aspx) about the Application.Caller property.  You've discovered the value of the #REF! error.  Google 'excel error 2023' for additional info.  I kinda doubt you can use this property, given that the caller is your C# program.

Comment: I've updated the question post and please have a look at the EIDT thanks.